# Get a pricebookEntryId for a custom object(having product2id field)

Tags: apex, pricebook, pricebookentry

I have a custom object SapLine which is like opportunityLine, i.e has a product2 lookup field. The hierarchy is Opportunity-->OpportunityLineItem, SapOrder-->SapLine. I created a PricebookId field on SapOrder, which is populated from Opportunity.Pricebook2Id.

And two triggers:

1. After insert on OpportunityLineItem - creates a SapLine and populates the product field with a product from OpportunityLineItem. Works fine.
2. After insert on SapLine - creates an OppLine and populates fields, the problem is that I cannot simply pass Product2Id, because the field is not writable. I need to use PricebookEntryId field but how do I get the pricebookEntryId from SapLine?

I thought of adding a before insert on SapLine where you would populate a custom field pricebookEntryId, to later use it for OppLine.PricebookEntryId using the following method:

Having SapOrder.PricebookId and SapLine.Product2Id I can SOQL PricebookEntry

```
[SELECT id FROM PricebookEntry WHERE Product2id IN: lstOfProducts AND Pricebook IN: lstOfPricebooks]
```

How do I map pricebookEntryId to a specific SapLine?

Comment: It's kind of hard to tell what you are asking with such a brief title. I tried to clean it up but I'm not certain of your question, so that makes it difficult.

Comment: Should I rewrite the question or the title?

Comment: I'm not sure. Mostly the body; we can help with the title if it still needs refining after that. Are you using just one pricebook? If you are using multiple, do you know which one a given `SAPLine` corresponds to? Do you know the `Product2Id` on the `SAPLine` and just need to get the corresponding `PricebookEntry`?

Comment: I'm using multiline Pricebook and use a PricebookId__c field on SapOrder(SapLine's Parent) and Product2Id is known as well. I just need to find a corresponding Pricebook Entry

Comment: What is OppLine in the second point? Is it a custom object or the standard OppLineItem

Comment: It's a custom object with a Product2 lookup